# How would I go about storing data with this kind of app?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, storing-data

I have this idea for an app (mainly for personal use) to write down homework or upcoming project due dates and save them, and maybe add alarms to help me not procrastinate.

My question is: how would I store assignments? I never actually made an app that stores user input so I don't know where to start. From what I know I can either start up an SQL db or use Shared Preferences which I'm not familiar with both. So my question is what's the advantages and disadvantages of either?

Comment: This question will get downvoted all day long because it is opinion based. Try doing some reasearch/writing some code and come back with a more concise question that can't be easily answered with Google

Comment: A ToDo list is normally created by using a db. And an interface. A SharedPreference is simply not adequate. If you search for `TaskButler`, you'll find a full source code doing exactly what you want: a database based ToDo list with alarm scheduling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bulk amount of data and you want to store it in ordered way then you can use SQL db. In SQL db you can also do indexing.

In case of small data storage you can use shared preferences.

In your case you should definitely use db.

Check the official documentation, you will get more clear idea :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html